# Calculating density of all positions using rolling window in R

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this has been covered somewhere else, but I cannot find a simple solution.

My data is arranged like this (these represent positions of variation or **SNPs**):

```
83353
83364
83402
83530
83539
83728
83929
83932
83950
83998
84001
84136
84148
84184
84187
84190
84205
84241
84247
84250
84253
84259
84264
```

Now I want to calculate the density of these SNPs at different positions, i.e. what is the # of SNPs around position **83929**?

I would like to do something akin to rollapply, where I can calculate how many of the SNPs can be found +/-50 [i.e. 83879-83979 range] (and +/-100 and +/-500 etc).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: tried to clarify SNPs

Comment: Please clarify what is SNP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt, let z be a vector with SNP positions.

```
window <- 50
lapply(z, function(x){
  m <- x + window #window max
  n <- x - window #window min
  seq = n:m #all positions from min to max
  return(length(z[z%in%seq])) #number of snp found in seq
  })
```